# Java must be installed on this system to use this when using dataflow flex template python

Tags: python, java, sql, apache-beam

I'm using SQL transform of apache_beam python and deploy to Dataflow by Flex Template. The pipeline show the error: `Java must be installed on this system to use`. I know the SQL transform of beam python using Java, I researched the way to add Java to pipeline but all failed.
Can you give any advice on how to fix this error? Thank a lot.

Comment: So, do you have Java installed? Which version? Is it a version that is compatible with what the tool you are using expects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have either Java8 or Java11 installed locally to start a Java expansion service to expand your SqlTransforms into Java SDK transforms. This is pipeline construction different from later pipeline execution and could be where your issue occurred.